# Is it possible to publish an asp.net 2012 web application to azure?

Tags: asp.net, azure

I tried to publish a web app from asp.net 2012 to azure but it gives an error "Error 1 Package/Publish task Microsoft.Web.Publishing.Tasks.CreateProviderList failed to load Web Deploy assemblies. Microsoft Web Deploy is not correctly installed on this machine. Microsoft Web Deploy v3 or higher is recommended. "
I tried installing it but the same error exists.

Comment: Any updates? Are you able to deploy your web application (web deployment package) to Azure app service now?

Answer (score 1):

Sure, Azure App Services can be used like an IIS Container.
If Visual Studio fails to publish, you could upload your application via FTP or by using auto-deploy from a GIT repository.

Once the application is deployed, Azure will read the Web.config file, so you can set up your application environment there.

Answer (score 1):

You have installed Microsoft Web Deploy v3, you can try to run MSDeploy.exe command directly to deploy a web application (web deployment package) to Azure app service web app. The following command works fine for me, please refer to it.

```
MSDeploy.exe
  -source:package="C:\testapp\WebApplication1.zip"
  -dest:auto,
        computerName="https://{my_app_name}.scm.azurewebsites.net/MSDeploy.axd?site={my_app_name}",
        username="{user_name}",
        password="{password}",
        authtype="Basic",
        includeAcls="False"
  -verb:sync
  -disableLink:AppPoolExtension
  -disableLink:ContentExtension
  -disableLink:CertificateExtension
  -setParamFile:"C:\testapp\WebApplication1.SetParameters.xml"
  -allowUntrusted
```

Note:

- You can get `username` and `password` from publish profile on
  Azure portal;
- For more information about deploying a web application using MSDeploy.exe, you can refer to [this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-forms/overview/deployment/web-deployment-in-the-enterprise/deploying-web-packages#using-msdeployexe).